# "Elegant" CruiseControl.Net and WiX integration

Tags: msbuild, wix, cruisecontrol.net, wix3

I am trying to integrate the automatic generation of MSI installers with my CruiseControl.Net installation. I can see how I can manually build an MSBuild file that calls **candle** and then **light**, but I need to make it build installers that can do upgrades, so can I use the BuildLabel (or something of that area) to regenerate new GUIDs for the newer versions?

I have already separated out the configurable parts of the WiX definitions, so it might be easier to hand roll a script or something.

Any help would be appreciated - especially working examples!

Thanks (as usual) in advance

Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Product/@Id="*" to let WiX generate product codes for upgrades. And you don't have to call candle.exe and light.exe manually; use the .wixproj templates to create MSBuild project files that use wix.targets.

Comment: Bob,
Thanks for the answer, I'm a bit of a beginner at WiX, so do you have an example?
Thanks

Comment: If you install WiX with Visual Studio, you can create new .wixproj files from File|New Project. If you don't use Visual Studio, you can download the WiX source .zip file; there are 68 .wixproj files there to choose from.